# To set a post is new/old in vertical scrolling

Tags: plugins

Firstly, I already got my answer. I am just updating the question so that everyone can understand what exactly i wanted. Previously i didn't ask in a proper way. In my plugin i have shown vertical scrolling posts. The post which is less than 10 days long that should contain an image(Banner containing 'New' written on it) along with the title of post. And after 10 days the image should disappeared automatically.

```
 <marquee onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 2, 0);" behavior="scroll" width="100%" loop="infinite" direction="up" scrollamount="2" scrolldelay=".0001" height="300">

 <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=10' ); ?>
 <?php
 echo human_time_diff(get_the_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) )?>
 <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
 <?php
 if ( human_time_diff()>1 ) {?>
 <li class="noticboard"><h3><?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?>&nbsp;</h3> <p> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p> </li>
  <?php } else {
 ?>
  <li class="noticboard"><h3><?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?>&nbsp;<img src='wp-content/plugins/scrolling-notice-board/icons/new.gif' /></h3> <p> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p></li>
<?php}
?>
 <!--<li><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 100);?></li>-->
 <?php endwhile;?>
</marquee>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] as this is really not a question but simply a dump of code that makes no sense :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 2, 0);" behavior="scroll" width="100%" loop="infinite" direction="up" scrollamount="2" scrolldelay=".0001" height="300">
    <?php 
        $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=10' ); 
        $now = current_time('timestamp');
        $still_new = 60*60*24*10; // 10 day window
        while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();

            if ( $now - get_the_time('U') > $still_new ) { ?>
                <li class="noticboard"><h3><?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?>&nbsp;</h3> <p> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p> </li>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <li class="noticboard"><h3><?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?>&nbsp;<img src='wp-content/plugins/scrolling-notice-board/icons/new.gif' /></h3> <p> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p></li>
            <?php } ?>
     <!--<li><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 100);?></li>-->
    <?php endwhile;?>
</marquee>
```

It uses the difference in the unix timestamp between now and the date of the post to calculate whether the post is 10 days old or not.
`$still_new = 60*60*24*10; // 10 day window` just allows you to set a window (10 days here) during which the 'new' image will be shown.

Comment: Hey thanks... it really solved my problem. although didnt asked in a proper understandable way but you still got it.thanks once again.